# How to make GET request with a complex object?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I try to make `GET` request via WebApi with complex object.
Request is like this:

```
[HttpGet("{param1}/{param2}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetRequest(string param1, int param2, [FromBody] CustomObject[] obj)
{
    throw new NotImplementException();
}
```

Where `CustomObject` is:

```
[DataContract]
public class CustomeObject
{        
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

How do I compose a valid GET request?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could show a [mcve] of your client side code showing what you have tried so far.

Comment: You are asking to many questions in one question. Also your `CustomObject` is not complex at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to bind a request model in WebAPI GET request with route attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24075892/how-to-bind-a-request-model-in-webapi-get-request-with-route-attribute)

Comment: What would the URL look like to call that action?

Comment: A GET request has no body. Therefore, it's impossible to bind any data as `FromBody`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`[FromBody] CustomObject[] obj` ... `GET` request has no message body and thus you should change it to `FromUri`.

Sure, take a look at [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api#using-fromuri)

```
public class GeoPoint
{
    public double Latitude { get; set; } 
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
}

public ValuesController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri] GeoPoint location) { ... }
}
```

Request would be like below, essentially you pass the entire object data as query string

```
http://localhost/api/values/?Latitude=47.678558&Longitude=-122.130989
```

An array of object example can be found in another post [pass array of an object to webapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13962748/pass-array-of-an-object-to-webapi)

Comment: can you write example request to test this?

Comment: It helps for a single object. The OP has an array. try showing that as well

Comment: Also recheck action this is for asp.net-core, which no longer uses `HttpResponseMessage`

Comment: @Nkosi, that won't affect anything, return type can be changed but the working remain same (i.e, parameter binding). So the example makes it pretty clear

Comment: it does affect the response though. But I see what you are saying. Check docs here to help with your answer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Answer (score 3):

If your complex object is defined by the server, you can model bind to it through the URI and dot notate the properties in the routing template. My advice is to keep this model to one level of properties. You *can* bind to more complex objects, but you'll quickly find yourself having to write your own model binder.

Note that your argument decorator will need to be changed to [FromUri] to bind a complex object through the Uri. Servers are not required to support GET bodies and most do not.

```
public class CustomObject
{ 
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

[HttpGet]
[Route("{foo.Name}/{foo.Email}")]
public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri]CustomObject foo)
{
   //...body
  return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatus.OK, foo);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass it as a stringified json or use the request body via post instead of get.

Comment: No, don't use `post` for `get` operation though the other suggestion make sense

Comment: Yes, obviously you should not use a POST as a GET, it was technically talking a solution